# Hot code deployment in Jetty

Tags: java, deployment, jetty

I am writing a Java EE application, using Jetty as the app server for convenience during development. Although (re)deployment is fast, I'd like if it was possible for Java code changes to be reflected immediately in the running server without restarting. (I'm already using the `useFileMappedBuffer` setting to see immediate changes to statically served content).

I've seen questions about using the Maven Jetty plugin and setting scanInterval in order to redeploy a web context, but that's not what I want to do. My Jetty server is started from within a Java application in Eclipse and I'd like code changes to be immediately reflected in the running server, as is possible with ordinary Java applications in Eclipse. I'm running the code "in place", i.e. not building and deploying a WAR file first.

I realise that web apps have their own class loaders in order to conform to the servlet spec, but I don't mind risking non-standard behaviour to get changes deployed more rapidly in development. I've tried using `WebAppContext.setClassLoader` to set the classloader to a "normal" classloader but to no avail.

Is it possible to do what I want? I believe JRebel claims to do it, but what's it doing that I'm not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect to Jetty using [remote debug](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.1.v20140609/debugging-with-eclipse.html) from Eclipse, [Hot code replace](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) should be possible.

Remote debugging is enabled by adding following to Jetty start script:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787
```

Comment: I've just discovered that launching my application in debug mode (not even remote debug) enables hot code replace. I guess this is because I am running Jetty from within my application. Thanks very much.

Comment: @PeterSwords the thing to understand is that it is a feature of the JVM, not Jetty or the IDE. If the JVM is started in debug mode with that -Xdebug flag, hotswapping is enabled. Possibly you already figured that out, but I just followed up to make sure :)

Comment: Note that even with -Xdebug and hotswapping, this kind of behavior has limited usefulness, as there are many many (too many) places in the core classlib that cache values, objects, instances, reference to the original pre-swap states.  So if you experience oddities with behavior, just restart your webapp.

Comment: @Gimby -- yes, was just having a brain-freeze. I knew that class reloading was a JVM feature, just forgot it only works when running in debug. I thought Jetty was doing something to defeat it, but it isn't. I understand the limitations, but when doing minor tweaks on my own classes I still find it useful. Jetty is superfast to relaunch anyway, which is why I'm using it and not my eventual target app server, but might slow down as the application grows.

Answer (score 0):

Even the ordinary Java application needs to be restarted to see code changes.

Basically your options are:

1. Restart Jetty (you said you don't want that).
2. Make Jetty scan for application changes and allow hot redeploy if changes are detected (you said you don't want that).
3. Attach a remote debugger which then does hot-swap your code changes (see answer of Amila). This is limited to method body changes and therefore not really useful.
4. Use JRebel which provides a useful hot-swap implementation and also can pick up configuration changes for many frameworks.
5. Use a web framework which implements a *proprietary* hot-swap implementation based on throw-away-classloaders (e.g. [Tapestry](https://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html) or [Civilian](http://www.civilian-framework.org/doc-development.html#reload)).